# How to create Multiple Data frames Dynamically in a For Loop in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Array[string] which has the value ["DF1" , "DF2", "DF3"]

I have values like below in my config file.

```
DF1=select * from TB1
DF2=select * from TB2
DF3=select * from TB3
```

I need to create 3 Data frames dynamically in a  For loop by unloading the respective tables.

lets say my Array name is ARRAY1.

My code would be

`for (for1 <- ARRAY1){val $for1+_DF = spark.sql(for1)}`

Above is just kind of pseudo code.

please help me by providing the correct code syntax.

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
scala> val queries = Map(
                          "df1" -> "select * from tb1",
                          "df2" -> "select * from TB2",
                          "df3" -> "select * from TB3"
                      ) // After reading from config file.
```

```
scala> 

queries
.values
.par
.map(spark.sql)
.foreach(_.show(false)) 

// Used .par for parallel loading & all three DataFrame object will be in list & you can do any operation on that, here i am using show function to display values

+---+
|id |
+---+
|1  |
|2  |
|3  |
|4  |
|5  |
|6  |
|7  |
|8  |
|9  |
+---+

+---+
|id |
+---+
|1  |
|2  |
|3  |
|4  |
|5  |
|6  |
|7  |
|8  |
|9  |
+---+

+---+
|id |
+---+
|1  |
|2  |
|3  |
|4  |
|5  |
|6  |
|7  |
|8  |
|9  |
+---+
```

Comment: Not sure if parallel loading is particularly useful here as spark dataframes are already lazy themselves.

Comment: You can check that .. add some sleep time inside map function

Comment: along with .par ..We might need to change job scheduler default  to Fair Scheduler Pools.. for more info https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html

Comment: But all these loads needs to be stored in different dataframe how to dynamically give the name that was my major question.